# Printer unable to print "blank pages"

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, cronjob

I'm using [Xerox DocuPrint CP305 d](http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.sg/en/Products/ColourPrinters/DocuPrintCP305d.aspx). For some reason, I'm unable to get "blank files" printed.

If there are contents within the file —e.g. the word "test", or even just a blank space character— the file gets printed successfully.

However, if there are no contents in the file (a "byte-less" file), the printer doesn't print the file.

What is causing this behavior? Why is the printer not printing "blank files"?

Do other printers have this problem too?

Comment: What happens when you try to print a test page? Not by writing in a blank document. . .

Comment: @zain.ali, Test page is fine. I could print everything and anything, Everything is fine, except for blank files, weird huh?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. . . why are you printing blank documents?

Comment: @zain.ali, Batch printing. (Would prefer not to elaborate.)

Comment: I'd bet there is an option to "optimize" the printing in this way. Look into the printer manual and/or settings for something similar to `[ v ] Do not print empty pages`

Comment: @Hannu, I've scoured through the printer's settings (via web browser interface). There doesn't seem to be such an option. http://www.fujixerox.co.jp/ews_help/ap/iso88591/docuprint_cp305/index.html Do you mean that that's a common option which exist in other printers?

Comment: A zero byte file has nothing to send to the printer, it is just a directory entry.  Printing is not the only thing you can't do with it.  If the printer just sits there, it has printed the entire contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

In the driver, click on the Advanced Settings tab and untick "Skip blank pages".

Note that, to make this permanent, you have to do it from Printing Defaults. Go to Printer Properties, click the Advanced tab, and the Printing Defaults button. Then proceed as above.

If you are printing via a server, you need to change the setting on the server, or it will not stay the default on the PC.

Finally, for a Mac, see this link:
http://m1-onlinesupport.fujixerox.com/driver_downloads/DP225D/DP225D-OUG/SFP-OUG-EFX-0312_140917/html/index.html#GUID-C359E783-56C0-44B1-994A-64E44FDC33E8_81#KEY=skip%20blank%20page

Comment: That "Skip blank pages" option doesn't exist for CP305d:  See http://i.stack.imgur.com/r9o0u.png (huge image)

Comment: I misread it for CM305, which I have at home. However, according to http://www.manualslib.com/manual/543478/Xerox-Docuprint-Cp305-D.html?page=130 it should be there.

Comment: You could try reinstalling the driver (after removing it from Print Server Properties), or try the PostScript driver.

Comment: This is odd, the manual for the CP305d isn't even on Xerox website. Where did manualslib get that copy from?

Comment: It's not a Xerox printer, but a Fuji Xerox printer (they're not sold in the US). See http://onlinesupport.fujixerox.com/processDriverForm.do?ctry_code=AU&lang_code=en&d_lang=en&corp_pid=DPC305D&rts=null&model=DocuPrint+CP305+d&type_id=5&lang_list=en&source=fxpc . My CM305DF is the same printer, but with a scanner.

Comment: @Pacerier Any luck yet?

Comment: No luck. I see you're having this problem too.

Comment: No, I do not have the problem. My driverlets me select printing of blank pages, and your driver should, too